# How to know hierarchy of property location in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection

For example i have following classes.

```
public class Level1
{
    public int intprop;
    public Level2 level2;
}

public class Level2
{   
    public string strprop;
    public Level3 level3;
}

public class Level3
{
    public float fltprop;
}
```

Now if i get fltprop, then how to know this property hierarchy is like this  **Level1.level2.level3.fltpro** ?

Is there any way in reflection to know the hierarchy of property location?

## Update:

If you look into the class Level1 to Level3, you can see that fltprop is residing inside Level1 => level2 => level3 => fltprop.

now by using reflection if i get fltprop as  PropertyInfo, then can i know this property is from Level1 => level2 => level3 ? means that taking propertyinfo then i have know this property's root level3 then knowing level3's root level2 then knowing level2's root is level1.

Comment: Generally: no. All you have is an object; that object could be used in many different places, or could be accessible from multiple routes in the same graph. The only way you can express something like that is if you start from an expression tree, i.e. `Expression<Func<Level1,float>> expr = x => x.Level2.Level3.fltprop;` - if you have *that*, then the answer becomes "yes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way in reflection to know the hierarchy of property location?

No. There isn't.

When you read the property (actually it is a field right now), you just have a value. No information about the type of the object you read it from is available. When you have the object itself (`Level3` object), there is no way compiler or runtime can tell you where did you get that object from. Maybe you just created a new instance of `Level3`, or maybe you read it from a property of another object. You just know that, not the runtime.

EDIT:

Suppose you pass a `PropertyInfo` for `fltprop`, along with an object of type `Level3` to a method. All the information the method has is that the property name is `fltprop`, and it is from `Level3` type. This doen't tell the method that *where do the `Level3` **object** you passed to the method come from*. This is also not stored in the `Level3` type information. Actually, when you read the type information for `Level3`, no matter how you get the type, it is the same:

```
var type1 = level3Obj.GetType();
var type2 = level1Obj.level2.level3.GetType();
var type3 = typeof(Level3);
var type4 = fltpropPropertyInfo.ReflectedType;

Console.WriteLine( type1 == type2 ); // outputs 'true'
Console.WriteLine( type2 == type3 ); // also outputs 'true'
Console.WriteLine( type3 == type4 ); // also 'true'
```

Comment: if you are right, say for example by using reflection i am looping through level1 properties and finding  property fltprop. then i am setting value by propertyinfo.setvalue(...). then we can see that this value is reflected while reading from level1. so why can not we know from where it has come?